# Create a list depending on variance of elements

Tags: python, while-loop, variance

I want to get a list of consecutive segments which are parts of a linestring (QGIS, Shapefile) and build up a nearly straight section of the linestring.

In the moment I can calculate the azimuth of the segments and put them to a list.

```
az_list = [260,263,260,209,245,339,337,343]
```

So at first I thought about to fill up a new list with the elements of the `az_list` until the variance is to high.

Example:

The first three values of `az_list` 260, 263, 260 built up a nearly straight section of a line. I check the variance of these three values with:

```
import numpy as np
np.var([260, 263, 260])    # result: 2.0
```

And for the last three one:

```
np.var([339,337,343])    # result: 6.22...
```

Knowing that, I could determine that for a variance `var` a section is straight when `var > 0` and `var < 10` and if the list is empty (which will be the start point) `math.isnan(np.var(az_list))` returns `False`.

I start to put the first three values from `az_list` to the new list `straight_list`. With this code  I tried to make this running but it returns an empty list.

```
straight_list = []
while not math.isnan(np.var(straight_list)) and np.var(straight_list) != 0 and np.var(straight_list) < 10:
    for i in az_list:
        straight_list.append(i)
```

Finally a want to achieve a list of list where the straight sections are stored, like:

```
straight_list = [[260,263,260],[339,337,343]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following solution:

```
import numpy as np

az_list = [260,263,260,209,245,339,337,343]

straight_list = []
sublist = []
for az in az_list:
    sublist.append(az)
    if np.var(sublist) > 10:
        if len(sublist) > 2:
            straight_list.append(sublist[:-1])
        sublist = [az]

if len(sublist) > 1:
    straight_list.append(sublist)

print(straight_list)  # [[260, 263, 260], [339, 337, 343]]
```